# determine the conjugates of permutation

Tags: abstract-algebra

Determine the number of conjugates in $S_7$ of the permutation 
$$\sigma=(2,3,1,5,6,4,7)$$
We use the notation $\sigma=(\sigma(1),\sigma(2),\cdots,\sigma(7))$. For example: $\sigma(1)=2, \sigma(2)=3, \sigma(7)=7$.

So, conjugate means $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1}$, right? I cannot find any quick way to do that other than try the $\tau$ one by one. I found that $\sigma$ is actually the product of $(2,3,1)$ and $(5,6,4)$. Is this useful to find the conjugates in some smarter way?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For conjugates in $S_n$ it is typically easier to work with "cycle notation", so if your mapping is:

$\sigma = \begin{pmatrix}1&2&3&4&5&6&7\\2&3&1&5&6&4&7\end{pmatrix}$

we can write this more compactly as: $(1\ 2\ 3)(4\ 5\ 6)$

and thus $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1} = (\tau(1)\ \tau(2)\ \tau(3))(\tau(4)\ \tau(5)\ \tau(6))$

This is a product of $2$ disjoint $3$-cycles, and it is not hard to show that any pair of disjoint $3$-cycles is conjugate to $\sigma$. So we can just count these.

It is typical to list a $3$-cycle $(a\ b\ c)$ so that $a < b$ and $a < c$. In $S_7$, this gives us $5$ choices for $a$.

If we choose $a = 1$, we have $6$ choices for $b$, and $5$ choices for $c$, giving $30$ $3$-cycles of the form $(1\ b\ c)$. This will exhaust all $3$-cycles that do not fix $1$.

If we choose $a = 2$, we now have $5$ choices for $b$, $4$ choices for $c$, so $20$ more $3$-cyles (we now have listed ALL $3$-cycles moving $1$ or $2$).

Continuing in this way, we see we have:

$30 + 20 + 12 + 6 + 2 = 70$ $3$-cycles in all.

Now we count the ways we can pick $2$ disjoint $3$-cycles.

If we choose $(a\ b\ c)$ first, the remaining $3$-cycles are permutations of $\{1,2,3,4,6,7\}- \{a,b,c\}$, which has $4$ elements. Picking a second disjoint $3$-cycle is thus equivalent to counting how many $3$-cycles there are in $S_4$. There are $8$, as can easily be verified.

This gives us $70\cdot8 = 560$ such choices, however, since these pairs commute:

$(a\ b\ c)(h\ k\ m) = (h\ k\ m)(a\ b\ c)$, so we have counted these twice, giving us $280$ *distinct* pairs of disjoint $3$-cycles, and thus $280$ conjugates of $\sigma$.

Comment: Thank you! How can you prove that $\tau\sigma\tau^{-1} = (\tau(1)\ \tau(2)\ \tau(3))(\tau(4)\ \tau(5)\ \tau(6))$ or just $\tau(1,2,3)\tau^{-1} = (\tau(1)\ \tau(2)\ \tau(3))$? Is it a general or useful conclusion? Thank you!

Comment: Yes it is quite general, see: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1185902/23285